# Cannot reproduce "string or binary data would be truncated" error

Tags: sql, sql-server

For a 10 minute period yesterday, a SQL stored procedure kept throwing the error "string or binary data would be truncated" when it was executed via my webserver. However, when I ran the exact same SQL command via Microsost SQL Server Management Studio there was no error.

In the SP there is only one insert statement; here's an abstraction of it:

```
DECLARE @TempTable table (Row1 varchar(25), Row2 varchar(4), Row3 int)
INSERT INTO @TempTable (Row1,Row2,Row3)
SELECT DISTINCT
  A.Value
  ,RIGHT(A.Text,4)
  ,CAST(ISNULL(A.Thing,'0') as int)
FROM ActivityTable A
```

In the database Activity table, each of those rows is defined as varchar(25) though Thing is always used for integers (stored as varchar, yes it's stupid). On the face of it I can't see how any of those could exceed the insert column's size.

I tried commenting them out one-by-one, inserting an empty string instead. First I replaced A.Value with '' and refreshed the webpage that executes the procedure; there was no error. I assumed this was the problem column so I put it back to the original value, assuming this would bring back the error. Except it didn't, and since then the error hasn't reoccurred.

This SP has run without issues for months, and only broke for those 10 minutes yesterday. Last week I raised the compatibility level on my SQL server from 100 to 130, so I'm assuming that must be somehow connected. But it also seems to have been affected by me altering the procedure, in addition to being time-specific and user-specific.

Comment: If the data in ActivityTable constantly changes, it's normal to not be able to reproduce the issue 10 minutes past. Instead of comment the rows you could SELECT MAX(LEN()) of all the fields from your query

Comment: The "abstraction" is highly unlikely to be helpful here. You need to get to a point where you *can* reproduce the actual error you're experiencing. I can trivially sit down and write code that generates this error - but it's unlikely that it will resemble your actual code and therefore 0% helpful when I point out how to fix *it*.

Comment: If all the the fields have a size of 25 chars is really an odd problem. You are the only that manage that web server? Maybe the temporal problem was related to a coworker changing something, seeing that it makes sp fails, and reverting it quietly.

Answer (score 0):

1) In code you are declaring table @TempTable and inserting into @Temp

2) A.Value in some cases is longer then 25chars. Try to use LEFT(A.Value,25) instead. Or extend the column size.